# Algorithm of projection

Tags: algorithms, optimization, numerical-methods

Suppose $S$ is a compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by a sufficiently smooth level
set function $f$, that is, $S=\{s: f(s)=0\}.$

I am studying an algorithm that projects a point $x_{0}$on $S$, in the sense of finding an element $x_n$ of $S$ that minimizes $|x_n-x_{0}|$.
The algorithm is:

> Begin by setting $x_1=x_{0}$.
>
> Iterate as follows. Let $n(x)=\dfrac{\nabla f(x)}{|\nabla f(x)|}$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the scalar
>   product in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then:
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> y_k & = & x_k-\cfrac{f(x_k)}{|\nabla f(x_k)|}n(x_k),\\
> x_{k+1} & = & x_{0}-\langle x_{0}-y_k,\, n(y_k)\rangle \,n(y_k),
> \end{eqnarray*}

Stop when $x$ satisfies:

$\dfrac{|f(x)|}{|\nabla f(x)|}\leq\epsilon$ and  $|\quad|<\dfrac{x_{0}-x}{|x_{0}-x|},n(x)>|-1\,|\leq\epsilon$
for some fixed $\epsilon$.

When $x_{0}$is "close enough" to the surface, it seems to converge
(from empirical tests). But I do not know how to quantify this "close". Is there a sufficient condition on $x_{0}$ so that it converges
?

Comment: I'm not sure what the first stopping condition is intended to mean.

Comment: @EricStucky There was a misprint, it is corrected now.